# Vim: How to change text from within an indent script

Tags: vim, editor

I recently switched from Eclipse to Vim. I'm loving it. There are a few hangups I'm working on, but one of the ones I'm having lots of trouble with is the PHP doc comments. In eclipse I could type:

```
/** [enter]
```

and the next line would auto fill with

```
 *
```

So I'd have:

```
/**
 * [comment goes here]
```

I'm wondering if there's anything like this for vim. It seems there are some plugins to autogenerate doc comments by running a command, but I'd love to have it do them as I'm typing.

I was playing around with the PHP indent script (http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1120) and I got it to recognize when it's inside of a doc comment block, but I can't figure out how to get it to actually change the text and add a " * " after hitting enter when inside the block.

I've tried what I've seen other plugins do:

```
let @z = ' * '
put! z
```

tried this too:

```
exe 'normal!' '"zgp'
```

but no luck. Is this not possible from an indent script, and if not, how do I actually get Vim to recognize a doc comment block and act accordingly while I'm typing?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to mess around with the indentation files. Vim's `formatoptions` will do this for you and in a variety of languages (not just PHP).

Ensure you have `r` included in your `formatoptions`:

```
:setlocal fo+=r "to set
:set fo? "to query
```

You can include this in your `.vimrc` or in `.vim/ftplugin/php.vim` (if you just want to activate this for PHP).

For more information on `formatoptions` and file-type plugins, see:

- [`:help 'formatoptions'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27formatoptions%27)
- [`:help fo-table`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#fo-table)
- [`:help ftplugins`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#ftplugins)

Comment: This is the right way to go. As a fast summary of a very comprehensive answer, I'd say add `set fo+=r` to .vimrc.

Comment: Weird, this works when I have all plugins disabled and I set fo+=r, but when using the stock PHP indent script (no modifications) and I set fo+=r, it doesn't work. set fo? == "qrowcb" ...any ideas? Is there another setting that could be disabling this?

Comment: Ok, seems to be "filetype plugin on" in my vimrc that was causing fo+=r not to work...specifically something in ftplugin/php.vim (or a script it loads maybe). Is there anything bad about not loading the ftplugins, or is there a way to force comments to work after it loads?

Comment: I can't see anything in `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/php.vim` that would disable comment formatting. You could try sticking stuff in your after-directory (see `:he after-directory`).

Comment: If you suspect a script is changing the value of one of your options, `:verbose set formatoptions` (for example) will tell you from where `fo` was last set.

Answer (score 1):

Would adding the below code to your vimrc do something similar to what you want?

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.php setlocal formatoptions+=r formatoptions+=o
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.php setlocal comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,:#
```

I currently can't quite figure out how to make it work without overriding the `<!-- --->` commenting, which this does. I.e. this will break auto-indenting with `<!-- -->` comments.

Edit. Added `://,:#` to `comments` as Johnsyweb's distribution does.

Comment: `comments` should be set automatically by the supplied `php.vim` indentation script. `<!-- [...] -->` comments are part of HTML syntax.

Comment: @Johnsyweb Yes, but the above snippet overwrites that by doing `comments=...`. If I instead did `comments+=...`, the /* */ style comments don't work properly --- I'm not sure why.

Comment: Works for me out-of-the-box: `comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://,:#`

Comment: Your distribution seems to be different from the OP's and from mine. However, what probably doesn't work for you now is doing `<!-- -->` comments and have the middle parts of those automatically indented (which is the default comments content for me --- `comments=s:<!--,m:    ,e:-->`). Am I correct?

Comment: I don't know how you determine that my distribution is different since `formatoptions` is `tcq` by default and so with `r` unset I wouldn't expect the comment formatting to work as requested. You are correct insofar as I don't have HTML syntax enabled for a PHP file but I didn't expect this, I prefer one language per source file.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your vimrc:

```
let g:PHP_autoformatcomment=1
```

I'm on a Mac and it seems to be enabled by default. Functions exactly how you stated.